# Taglibsharp: Can't see Album Cover on Windows Media Player and Microsoft Groove

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, taglib-sharp

I'm making a program that adds Album Covers to MP3 Files. The Covers are visible on MP3 Players, Android Phones and VLC Media Player, but not on Windows Media Player or Microsoft Groove. My program uses Taglibsharp

```
TagLib.File trackFile =  TagLib.File.Create("/path/to/mp3");
Picture picture = new Picture("/path/to/image");
picture.Type = PictureType.FrontCover;
picture.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
trackFile.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[1] { picture };
trackFile.Save();
```

Hope you can help me

**EDIT:**

I just had to add two lines of code to solve the problem:

```
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3; // Added...
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true; // lines

TagLib.File trackFile =  TagLib.File.Create("/path/to/mp3");
Picture picture = new Picture("/path/to/image");
picture.Type = PictureType.FrontCover;
picture.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
trackFile.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[1] { picture };
trackFile.Save();
```

Hope this helps you